# Upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04 LTS not working

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

Below is the commands I have triggered

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt ugprade
sudo reboot
sudo ufw allow 1022/tcp comment 'Temp open port ssh tcp port 1022 for upgrade'
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

After this system gives error. Below is the logs

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,240 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,241 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                       
Hit https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease                  
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease               
Hit http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease             
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                     
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease                
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/slgobinath/safeeyes/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Hit https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                
Hit http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                           
Hit https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease                                                                                                                                   
Fetched 109 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                  
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Can someone help me for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common error with release-upgrade is shown in a common error message

> This was likely caused by:
>
> - Unofficial software packages not
>     provided by Ubuntu Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge
>     package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and try the upgrade
>     again.

You can check logs (/var/log/dist-upgrade/) for the cause; remove those packages and repeat until `do-release-upgrade` is happy to proceed.

A faster alternative, or a backup if you have problems, is install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the 'something-else' option over your existing installation. Ensure you select your existing partitions but **ensure** the 'format' box is **unchecked**.  This will cause

- your existing (added) packages are noted
- system directories are emptied
- new Ubuntu is installed
- your additional packages noted earlier are re-installed if available
- on completion you are requested to allow reboot

User directories are not touched, however please note this assumes you did **NOT** have format ticked.

Of course - backup first, though you should have already done that :)

*Also note this can be useful as it allows you change/skip releases*

Comment: ps:  If it were my machine, I'd still try and find the problem and explore how many packages are problematic and start removing.  I rarely do the 'something-else', though usually wish I had (a re-install with something-else takes about 20 minutes for the average system; 17mins is/was the average for a 18.04 install + 3 mins for additional packages re-install)

Comment: Nice, I'd never heard of the automatic reinstall of added packages on "something else" install over old version.

Comment: Most user config files are stored in $HOME, however if you have config files in any system directories, they'll get wiped - not an issue for most user (desktop) apps, but for some server tools this still can mean restores are required.

Answer (score 0):

When I've tried to start the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, I've been informed that the upgrader needs to disable all non-Ubuntu repositories and remove non-Ubuntu packages to proceed -- but for some reason that's not being offered.  Ubuntu therefore can't proceed with the upgrade (because the effect on your non-Ubuntu packages isn't predictable) and is aborting the upgrade.

The most reliable way to work around this is to make a full backup (in case you need to return to your current machine state), remove all your non-Ubuntu repositories and their packages, then process the upgrade and reinstall these additional items afterward (in agreeing versions).

Alternatively, after your backup, you could (probably more reliably, and in a similar amount of time) just do a clean install in the same space your system now occupies, restore your data from the backup, and reinstall (version compatible) non-Ubuntu items.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrades for LTS to newer LTS are possible:

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Edit the “Prompt=” line in the file to ” Prompt=lts ”, then

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```